# Differentiate ø and ae

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I do an SQL `ae` and `æ` are interpreted as the same (danish collation):

```
select * from directories where path='test.dk\kkl$\Faelles'
```

Is there anyway to do a query that handles æ and ae as unique?

Comment: Give us the exact collation. `utf8_general_ci` has no problems comparing these characters.

Comment: Your question's title says "**ø and ae**" while your question's body says "**ae and æ**". What is correct?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'ae' COLLATE Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AI = 'æ' COLLATE Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AI THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` yields `0`, even when using `_AI`, i.e., an accent-insensitive collation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used exactly @Heinzi's code here (he used the collation)
I just wanted to show how you can use it in a WHERE clause and in ORDER BY clause with a sample

At first I though you require NVARCHAR() data type but I see VARCHAR() also support Danish characters without an issue ( at least your sample )

```
declare @code nvarchar(100) = 'æ'
--declare @code nvarchar(100) = 'ae'

select * 
from Danish
where code = @code COLLATE Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AI 
--order by code COLLATE Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AI desc
```

So you need to set the Collation with COLLATE clause in WHERE clause or in ORDER BY for each condition or group by field,

After @Thomas' comment, I added following query.
It will produce seperate rows for 'æ' and 'ae'

```
SELECT
    path COLLATE Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AI, 
    migrate, ismigrationroot, 
    COUNT(*) as CNT 
FROM directories 
GROUP BY 
    path COLLATE Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AI,
    migrate,
    ismigrationroot 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1 and 
    ismigrationroot is not null
```

Comment: I tried above where would you add collate in following:  SELECT  path,migrate,ismigrationroot, COUNT(*) as CNT
FROM  directories 
GROUP BY path  ,migrate,ismigrationroot 

HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1 and ismigrationroot is not null

Comment: Please check my post, I added a second query after your comment. You should use COLLATE both with Select field and with Group By field at the same time

Comment: Thanks, its highly appreciated!